# callback in controller does not works for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this code in my controller:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController

before_filter :invitations_sent!

def new
 #code here
end

def create
 #code here
end

  private
   def invitations_sent!
    if current_user.invitations.size > 1
      return false
      format.js { render :text => "you can not send more invitations" }
    else
    return true
    end         
   end
end
```

I call to method new with:

```
<%=link_to "Invite Friends", new_invitations_path, :remote =>true, :id => "invite_to_friends" %>
```

**Why Can I access to methods new and create If I have sent 3 invitations?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used remote links before so I'm not sure about that part, but you definitely need `return false` to come after `format.js { }` if you want `format.js { }` to actually run. Once ruby hits a return statement method execution stops.

**UPDATE:**
It's not totally clear from your comment what you changed. But if you want the render to happen at all that method should look like this:

```
def invitations_sent!
  if current_user.invitations.size > 1
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render :text => "you can not send more invitations" }
    end
    return false
  else
    return true
  end         
 end
```

Nevermind, the render block was not ok. It should be wrapped in a `respond_to` block like above.

Comment: Thank you. Could you write a example for above method in the question?. Thank you very much!

Comment: If I write this: `if current_user.invitations.size > 1
   format.js 
   return false
  end` I get the error: **ArgumentError (too few arguments)...**

Comment: The lines that Throw the error are this lines: `format.js { render :text => "you can not send more invitations" }
    return false` when this condition is fulfilled

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer but my first step in figuring it out would be to answer these questions:

1) Is your before filter actually being called?

2) Is current_user correct, in the filter?

3) Is current_user invitations correct?

4) Does `return false` actually get executed?

You can look at what's going on in your filter by adding `raise` statements or calls to `puts`.

Comment: Thank you, I get corret `current_user.invitations.size` in log. For this case **2**. Then If I can see in log the correct `current_user.invitations.size`. Why does not fired the return false of the condition? :O. If I put in method `def invitations_sent!
return false
end` Nothing happens :O. In other controllers works fine this filters for me

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to return true/false.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/json' }
end
```